# Can "blossom out" be used to describe a person that laughs happily?

Tags: word-usage

I read a sentence online like this:

> There is a moment when girls ***blossom out*** in the twinkling of an eye, and become roses all at once.

Is "blossom out" used properly here ? Are there any words or phrases that can be used to describe someone who laughs happily?

Comment: "Blossom", when used to describe a person's behavior, generally refers to someone who becomes prettier, more friendly, more skilled in some activity, or some other such improvement, with the particular characteristic that improves being implied through the adjacent context.  It wouldn't normally be used to describe laughing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a moment when girls blossom out in the twinkling of an eye, and become roses all at once.
This is the poetic use of -blossom- as a metaphor.As a poet I support such uses. Blossom out--is also okay as the writer wishes to impress upon the fact that the girl openly laughed as if a shying bud--a shying lass left her reluctance and giggled open-heartedly. Dictionaries are not needed for such explanations, poets are.

Answer (score 3):

First, I should point out that the preposition ‘out’ is not required with the verb ‘blossom’, and is therefore not recommended for one learning English. Thus, the [Oxford Dictionary online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/blossom) does not include it in its illustration of the relevant definition:

> 1.1 Mature or develop in a promising or healthy way.
>   ‘their friendship blossomed into romance’
>   ‘the blossoming of experimental theatre’

As you will also see from the definition cited (and the other definitions in the link) ‘blossom’ would not be used to describe “someone who laughs happily”. There are various phrases you could use depending on context and style — “bubbling with laughter” is common, if you are prepared to include the word ‘laughter’, otherwise you would probably have to make do with implication e.g. “her cheerful counternance”.

Answer (score 0):

It is correct and the essential meaning here is the full development physically (and maybe intellectually) of the girls.

Blossom out can be replaced with develop, but because it is being compared with roses, so blossom out will probably makes more (poetic!) sense.